# Two Dimensional Array width length and coordinates

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got this test from an online job application and i don't have any experience on 2d array.

1. A positive whole number range 1-9 representing the length of your city in city blocks
2. A positive whole number range 1-9 representing the width of your city in city blocks
3. An array containing all X coordinates representing Locker locations, each X coordinate range 1-9
4. An array containing all Y coordinates representing Locker locations, each Y coordinate range 1-9

Construct a 2-d grid of the city. Each element of the grid should be a positive whole number that specifies the number of blocks to the closest locker. The distance between two blocks is the sum of their horizontal and vertical distance (a move in the diagonal direction is therefore considered a distance of 2). Return your grid as 2d array of integers where the first index corresponds to the X dimension and the second index corresponds to the Y direction.

```
Example #1

Input
1. 3
2. 5
3. [1]
4. [1]

Output
012
123
234
345
456

Example #2

Input
1. 5
2. 7
3. [2, 4]
4. [3, 7]

Output
32345
21234
10123
21234
32323
43212
32101


static int[][] getLockerDistanceGrid(int cityLength, int cityWidth, int[] lockerXCoordinates, int[] lockerYCoordinates) {

}
```

Comment: I don't think we should implement the test for you, but I'll give you a hint: using dynamic programming will yield the best solution.

Comment: @DatNguyen test is done i just want to know the answer

Comment: There's as many answers as there is programmers. Your answer is the one you submitted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static int[,] getLockerDistanceGrid(int cityLength, int cityWidth, int[] lockerXCoordinates, int[] lockerYCoordinates){
int[,] array = new int[cityWidth,cityLength];
for(int i = 0; i < cityLength; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < cityWidth; j++)
    {
        int value = Math.Abs(i - (lockerXCoordinates[0]-1)) +
            Math.Abs(j - (lockerYCoordinates[0]-1));
        for(int k = 1; k < lockerXCoordinates.Count(); k++)
        {
            int current = Math.Abs(i - (lockerXCoordinates[k]-1)) + Math.Abs(j - (lockerYCoordinates[k]-1));
            value = Math.Min(value,current);
        }
        array[j,i] = value;
    }
}
return array;
}
```